# Can Visual Studio.NET 2008 integrate SQL 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Visual Studio 2008 ships with SQL 2005. I would like to integrate SQL 2008.

Are there significant reasons why one could not/ can not do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reasons at all, it's quite common to do so.  Just make sure you have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed for SQL Server 2008 support.